# What's the lowest-memory usage browser - or, how to reduce memory footprint of common browsers

Tags: windows-7, memory, browser

In a misguided attempt to save money, I bought myself a windows 7 netbook with just 1GB of RAM. Since I only wanted it for music, super-lightweight (i.e. Notepad) word processing and web browsing I figured I'd be okay.

The device is indeed fine for the first two tasks, but trying to use the web often kills the system, even with the built-in Internet Explorer 11. Animated Google Doodles are enough to bring everything to a crashing halt.

I know I could upgrade the RAM, but to add insult to injury, doing so will invalidate my warranty, so I'm not doing that until the guarantee expires. And it'll only take an extra 1GB anyway, so that's not much of a solution.

I've implemented the most common memory management improvements like increasing virtual memory, turning off inessential startup processes and the like, which gave me a bit extra, but not enough.

What are my options? Are there any other browsers with a lower memory footprint than IE11? Or are there some sensible configuration options I can take without destroying the browsing experience (i.e. short of turning off JavaScript)? Or am I doomed to spend my browsing life on my netbook using Lynx?

Comment: Have you looked at running Linux on it? Linux can be setup to use very little ram.

Comment: I did consider it, but I've got to confess I'm an inveterate Windows user, and I've never got on well with Linux. Could try setting it up as a dual-boot I suppose, but that's going to be awkward to implement on such a slow machine. I'd rather see if there's a windows-based solution first. Out of interest, which distro would you recommend for minimum memory usage?

Comment: Have you tried Opera and Maxthon?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [K-Meleon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Meleon) portable. It's base on Gecko engine which is from Firefox. I'm satisified with its feature, don't feel any difficulty switching from Google Chrome. Couldn't say if it's the lowest-memory usage brower, anyhow it uses memory much less than Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came through Dillo and QupZilla browsers. They are light weight browsers.

Dillo Developed on C & C++ , its still missing some minimum features but its good for a light weight browser where Browsing & viewing webpages is the matter.

Qupzilla is a combination of QT + Firefox browsers. I hope you are already familiar with firefox browser. So this is Firefox features with Qt Interface for application.

The URL are here:

http://www.qupzilla.com/

http://www.dillo.org/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue only with a 2GB LG laptop. Chrome ground my machine to a halt when I was working with docs, spreadsheets, etc. So I've just checked out a few browsers and monitored memory and CPU usage with Process Explorer, with tabbed Gmail, Facebook, Unrealitymag, an arb page, and localhost. Some results:
Green Browser about 250MB (but horrible interface). Opera V25 about 755MB. Chrome about 810MB. QTWeb about 220MB. And QTWeb has a nice interface! All of the browsers CPU usage was of a similar order of magnitude. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Opera Mobile for Desktop](http://www.opera.com/pl/developer/mobile-emulator). It is very lightweight, using only 20MB at startup, and very fast, using Opera Turbo.

Alternatively, you can use [SlimJet](http://www.slimjet.com/) based on Chromium, which is lightweight and features an [automatic memory usage optimization](http://www.slimjet.com/blog/automatically-optimize-memory-usage-in-slimjet/).

There is also [Light](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lightfirefox/) based on Firefox, which has some components stripped off.